Will this shelving design safely hold 2100lbs?
I would like to add some built-in shelves to a room in my house.  It will hold several aquariums, so they need to be quite strong.
I’ve sketched out a plan (see below), but I’ve never built anything like this before and I’m wondering if this will work.
The shelves will be about 72 inches long, 22 inches deep, and there will be three of them.
Each shelf will need to support about 700 pounds, evenly distributed.
My idea is to support the back edge with a cleat attached to the four studs with GRK structural screws. The front of the shelves will be attached to 4x4 posts.
My plan for the shelves is to make them out of three-quarter inch plywood supported in the front by an LVL 2x4 spanning between the two 4x4s.  The plywood will be screwed into the LVL 2 x 4 and the cleat.  The plywood span between the front and back will be supported by 2x4 braces on on each end and every 16” on centers, screwed into the LVL and the back cleat.
I was going to cut dados in the 4x4s to support the LVL 2x4 and the plywood, and use structural screws to attach the LVL to the 4x4s.
I’m planning to use the LVL 2x4 to accommodate the long span. I realize that a center post would make this all easier, but for aesthetic and usability reasons, I really would like to avoid a center post.
The wall and the 4x4 posts both rest on the slab foundation.



evenly distributed?  how many aquariums on each shelf?  are they glass aquariums?

Wood sags under weight. The water in the aquaria will shift towards the lowest point, increasing strain there... exacerbating the tilt. Also, consider if the house construction itself can bear a concentrated load on that wall.

@jasen the number will vary by shelf and probably over time.  It’s designed to accommodate up different configurations. For instance it would fit 6 10 gallon tanks per shelf, 2 29 gallon tanks,  or a mixture.  They will be glass.

@DrMoishePippik "The water in the aquaria will shift towards the lowest point?"  No, unless the aquaria are sliding on the shelves.

@Huesmann, consider a shelf, sagging in the middle (or towards front). Now consider how the water will appear in the aquaria, no longer level.

Describe how they rest on the shelf.   Does the aquarium floor distribute the weight to a frame around the 4 sides or does it distribute the weight to the plywood all over the floor?  Will  smaller aquariums be resting in the middle of the plywood shelf away from all its edges?  You need a better analysis of how the weight gets from here to there.  For example, a large aquarium that transmits its weight through the frame would hardly use the plywood shelf.  A smaller one with a saggy plastic bottom might act differently.

Considering how much you'll be working with water, you should either use stainless steel hardware or, preferably, build the joints more like a deck where the hardware isn't supporting weight.

@Huesmann -- that was my initial reaction, too, but consider two aquaria side by side; a sagging shelf means the inner sides are lower than the outer.

Any slope resulting from sag is trivially tiny. The weight imbalance is a few pounds, max, and is probably overwhelmed by uneven distribution of gravel. This discussion is hilarious.

@DrMoishePippik your language may not be sufficiently clear here.  Are you talking about the lowest point of the shelf (which you say is sagging)?  Or of any one aquarium?  Even if the latter, the water will not shift, it will simply find level.  The amount of sag would need to be significant for a level change to be a problem.

The 2x4 rails will not be adequate. The walls of the aquarium are very strong in shear, but guidelines suggest full support anyway. This won't give you that. For a 72" span I'd want single or even doubled 2x6--something with a taller section.
Then, unless your aquariums are also 22" deep you need support under the plywood at the aquarium permiter. Don't rely on the plywood to span much at all.
Also, keep in mind the critical nature of diagonal bracing. If you use wall cleats you're covered. If not, you need something robust to prevent a flop. X-bracing of some sort or a back panel would do if well anchored.
Otherwise I think you're ok. Do consider a simple stack of concrete blocks with layered shelves, though. A pair of 4x6s (on edge) with no plywood would work well, even without plywood.
See also my answer to a similar question.
